# Android subactivity fails on power up

Tags: android

I'm fairly new to android programming, although a very experienced programmer and am trying to construct a Spanish vocabulary program.

I've constructed a main program with a couple of subactivities that start from the dropdown menu on the main activity. The subactivities start just fine if I begin with the main activity. I can go back and forth between the subs and the main without any problem.

When I power down the tablet with a subactivity active, then power back up, I get the message "Unfortunately (myapp) has stopped. When I press the OK button to acknowledge, it goes do the main activity, and from then on, works just fine, as long as I don't power down with a subactivity active.

There are no interactions between the activities (I am not returning data from one to the other).

I have searched for possible solutions to the problem, but most related problems have something to do with os errors than anything else.

Comment: There is no way to know what is happening without seeing some of your code such as one of the `Activities` that causes it to fail when powering down or knowing what the logcat says and probably seeing the main `Activity`.

Comment: Yeah, when you see "Unfortunately (myapp) has stopped." that generally means you should look at LogCat and see what exception was thrown.

Comment: Do you mean actual **power** down, or do you mean screen lock? If the latter, you'll want to debug your `onResume` and `onStart` code.

Comment: I didn't think, coming from a strictly PC/Web background that logcat would do you any good on a power up. Wrong again! I found that closing my cursor and trying to access it on a power-up was the cause of the problem. I guess that I'm just not familiar enough with the Android garbage collection process.